# Batch File: If file doesn't exist, create, if file does exist create a new one, compare two files, and delete the largest one

Tags: windows, batch-file, printing

I would like to create a batch file that exports a reg key to a folder on a server, but the file also needs to perform a few checks before and after.

Currently I have:

```
regedit /e "\\pdc\users\%username%\application data\printer registration.reg" "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Generic"
```

The above works perfectly to export the registry key, but as this batch file will be turned into a logon script, I would like for it to be a little more clever.

**1:** It needs to assess whether "*Printer Registration.reg*" already exists in that directory.If the file does not exist, it must continue to create the file "*Printer Registration.reg*" and then progress to number '#2' below.

If the file already exists, the script must export the registry key to a file called "**Printer Registration2.reg**", and then check to see if the file just created is larger than 625kb. If the file is larger than 625kb, or is the same size as the file that already exists as "*Printer Registration.reg*", delete "**Printer Registration2.reg**".

If it is less than 625kb and differs in file size to "*Printer Registration.reg*", then it must delete "*Printer Registration.reg*" and rename "**Printer Registration2.reg**" to "*Printer Registration.reg*".

**#2:** The resultant file must then be copied to the users Windows 7 desktop.

If anyone could help me with this task, I would be eternally grateful.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this,

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
net use A: "\\pdc\users\%username%\application data\" /persistent:no >> nul
set maxbytesize=625000
Set File1=printer_registration.reg
Set File2=printer_registration2.reg

:FILE_CHECK
if exist "\\pdc\users\%username%\application data\printer registration.reg" (
    regedit /e "\\pdc\users\%username%\application data\printer registration2.reg" "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Generic"
) else (
    regedit /e "\\pdc\users\%username%\application data\printer registration.reg" "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Generic"
    GOTO Copy_Final
)

:CHECK SIZE
CD A:
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%file1%') DO set size1=%%~zA
FOR /F "usebackq" %%B IN ('%file2%') DO set size2=%%~zB

:Compare
if %size2% GTR %maxbytesize% (
    Del "\\pdc\users\%username%\application data\printer_registration2.reg"
    goto Copy_Final
) 
if %size2% EQU %size1% (
    Del "\\pdc\users\%username%\application data\printer_registration2.reg"
    goto Copy_Final
) ELSE (
    Del "\\pdc\users\%username%\application data\printer_registration.reg"
    Ren "\\pdc\users\%username%\application data\printer_registration2.reg" "\\pdc\users\%username%\application data\printer_registration.reg"
    goto Copy_Final
    )

:Copy_Final
Copy "\\pdc\users\%username%\application data\printer registration.reg" %userprofile%\desktop

net use A: /delete /y
```

Comment: Ok, I am going to try this now and see how I get on.

Comment: It works up until the point of :Compare.
It closes at that point without making any further actions, like the :Copy_Final section.

Comment: No error message, it just closes. I have put a pause after the :Check Size section, and that pauses fine. Then I tried putting a pause after the :Compare section, and it never does, it just closes the box entirely.

Comment: Add `Echo %size1% %size2% ` before `:Compare` and see what outputs also code in my answer has been edited

Comment: I have done that and it just says ECHO is on.

Above it though, I can see the two lines that say "set size1=      " and "set size2=    "

Below it as it runs the first line of :Compare, I managed to print screen it before the screen shut. 
'It says 625000 was unexpected at this time.
if       GTR 625000'

Is it that the size is not being calculated?

Comment: script changes needed to add `enabledelayedexpansion` try it now

Comment: I have just retried. Unfortunately it is still coming up with `625000 was unexpected at this time. if [blank space] GTR 625000 (`

Comment: Unfortunately still not working. I have uploaded an image on this website. Hope this helps.. [link](http://postimg.org/image/ats99tcir)

Comment: i've done some more testing and found that if the file name has a space in it wont work does the file name `printer registration` need the space ? photo of working http://postimg.org/image/t5ppcrbyn/

Comment: Aah ok, no it doesn't need the space in between those words.

Would you mind pasting the working code in to the thread please so that I can copy and paste it, as I want to avoid making a mistake myself.

Comment: I had to make some changes to your code due to the Net Use command being disallowed by the restrictions on our network.

I have rearranged some of the processes, so that the two printer_registration files are copied locally, and then compared locally, which meant I no longer needed to map the drive.

I really appreciate your help! I have actually learnt a lot from the code you have given, so for that I really am eternally grateful.

The edited code, I pasted into your answer.

Thanks once again!